# split nesting array for use in php

Tags: php, arrays, split, nested

i have an array and want split them.may be two ,tree or more

```
array(
     name=>array(
                0=>asda.jpg,
                1=>kewj.jpg
                ),
     type=>array(
                0=>jpg,
                1=>jpg
                ),
     size=>array(
                0=>2133,
                1=>2222
                )
     )
```

i want split to two array or if more

```
array(
     name=>asd.jpg,
     type=>jpg,
     size=>2133
     )
```

and

```
array(
       name=>kewj.jpg,
       type=>jpg,
       size=>2222
      )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can achieve it like this

**Example**

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'name' => array(
          0 => 'asda.jpg',
          1 => 'kewj.jpg'
        ),
'type' => array(
          0 => 'jpg',
          1 => 'jpg'
        ),
'size' => array(
          0 => '2133',
          1 => '2222'
        )
);
$arraySplit = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            $arraySplit[$key2][$key] = $value2;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arraySplit);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => asda.jpg
        [type] => jpg
        [size] => 2133
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => kewj.jpg
        [type] => jpg
        [size] => 2222
    )

)
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Here it is in a function:
`function recastArray($array) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
            $newArray[$key2][$key] = $value2;
        }

    }
    return $newArray;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(recastArray($array));
echo "</pre>";`

Comment: @Difster Yes it is but i just make it in locally.. i didn't see that function.

Comment: I know, I was in the process of adapting a function I already had when you posted the answer, so I finished it and posted it anyway just to be helpful.

Comment: @alikarimi Please post your whole array..

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be the solution:

```
foreach ($array1 as $value) {

    for($node=0;$node<count($value);$node++){

        $arr[$node][] = $value[$node];
    }    
}
```

Thanks!